# How to call javascript function in a JS file to a controller using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem trying to call a javascript function in a JS file to a controller. I wanted to use the function in the JS file then return the value to a controller who calls that function.

Here is my code:
(JS File)

```
function getQueryString(url) {
    var arrSplit = url.split('?');
    return arrSplit.length > 1 ? url.substring(url.indexOf('?')+1) : '';
}
```

And I wanted to make a call like this in my controller.
(Controller)

```
private string DoSomething(){
     getQueryString("http://sample.com");
}
```

Is is this possible? Or if ever do you have any suggestions or any possible workarounds?

Comment: The question is not really clear. What you are exactly trying to achieve, Also, 3 lines of code does not do justice to the problem explanation.

Comment: I have edited my question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, MVC does not work that way. You cannot refer JS methods from your MVC controller. MVC controlled executes on the backend and just formulates your View. Once your HTML view is returned to the client, it executes there, And you JS is on the client-side. If you need to call a method in your JS on the browser side, from a server-side Controller, you need to use SignalR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know if there is an easier way to convert the javascript function to a controller function? Because I've tried converting it manually but I have a hard time doing it that is why I asked if this is possible.

Comment: I am not sure what you are exactly asking, but why can't you write the code on the backend side itself if you need to access that from the controller? If you need the URL, you can get that from the `Request` inside the controller action too.